# Capistrano 3.4.0 - stopped deploying

Tags: capistrano

I know there are lots of topics regarding Capistrano, but none helped in our case.

Capistrano 3.4.0 suddenly stopped deploying.

The error we get:

```
INFO [8fd2b54a] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/000.com/ as deploy@000.com
DEBUG [8fd2b54a] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/000.com/
^C(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Interrupt:

Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error:
```

I tried several recipes, but can't get what is wrong. 
Do you have any ideas?

Now I've got an error:

The deploy has failed with an error: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout

```
deploy@ip-000:~/dep$ cap production deploy --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
INFO [5c3bfd8b] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/00/ as deploy@00.com
DEBUG [5c3bfd8b] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/00.com/
^Ccap aborted!
Interrupt:
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.                                                                   rb:20:in `join'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.                                                                   rb:20:in `map'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.                                                                   rb:20:in `execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/coordinator.rb:21                                                                   :in `each'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:55                                                                   :in `on'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git                                                                   .rake:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in                                                                    execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in                                                                    invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchr                                                                   onize'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_w                                                                   ith_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in                                                                    invoke_prerequisites'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_p                                                                   rerequisites'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in                                                                    invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchr                                                                   onize'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_w                                                                   ith_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:16                                                                   :in `invoke'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/dep                                                                   loy.rake:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in                                                                    execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in                                                                    invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchr                                                                   onize'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_w                                                                   ith_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:16                                                                   :in `invoke'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/dep                                                                   loy.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in                                                                    execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in                                                                    invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchr                                                                   onize'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_w                                                                   ith_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:16                                                                   :in `invoke'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/fra                                                                   mework.rake:65:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/fra                                                                   mework.rake:64:in `each'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/fra                                                                   mework.rake:64:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in                                                                    execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in                                                                    invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchr                                                                   onize'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_w                                                                   ith_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `i                                                                   nvoke_task'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `b                                                                   lock (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `e                                                                   ach'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `b                                                                   lock in top_level'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `r                                                                   un_with_threads'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `t                                                                   op_level'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `bl                                                                   ock in run'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `s                                                                   tandard_exception_handling'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `ru                                                                   n'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/applicati                                                                   on.rb:15:in `run'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (requ                                                                   ired)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
The deploy has failed with an error:
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your `deploy.rb` in particulary the `set :repo_url,` part ?

It seems, your repo is not reacheable from your server, check `git` command and `ssh-agent`

It's a private repo ?

Comment: Sorry guys, my answer wasn't added somehow. The issue was with CloudFare. You need to change url for IPs. Hope that finding will help other guys! Thanks for getting back!